# Decide if $1^2+4^2+7^2+....(3n+1)^2$ is divisible by $n$, $3n+1$, $2n+1$ or $n+1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> The sum 
>   $$1^2+4^2+7^2+....(3n+1)^2$$ is divisible by
>   $$A) n$$
>   $$B) 3n+1$$
>   $$C) 2n+1$$
>   $$D) n+1$$

My try follows

$$\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\\
\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\\
\sum_{i=1}^n1=n$$

I can't go further 
What  should I do
Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you help me editing it ?

Comment: All the given options are wrong, it is enough to consider $n=3$.

Answer (score 3):

For the multiple choice question, the easiest way is to look at $n=1$.  Then the sum is $17$ and you can rule out all answers but A.

Comment: take $n=3$ the sum =$166$ which doesn't  divisible by $3$

Comment: You are correct.  This proves the question does not have a correct answer.  I was assuming there was one when I quit after ruling out B,C,D.

Answer (score 2):

$$1^2+4^2+7^2+....(3n+1)^2=\sum_{r=0}^n(3r+1)^2=\sum_{r=0}^n(9r^2+6r+1)=\\
=9\sum_{r=0}^nr^2+6\sum_{r=0}^nr+\sum_{r=0}^n1
\\=9 \cdot \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+6 \cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+ 1.(n
+1)
\\=n\Bigg(9 \cdot \frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+6 \cdot \frac{(n+1)}{2}+ 1\Bigg) + 1$$

Therefore, none of the options is correct.That one $'1'$ destroyed everything. :D

Comment: What is the difference of my answer?

Comment: Sorry @Arnaldo,we have similar answers, I didn't look while I was typing that you have already posted one.

Comment: No problem! I can delete mine! (+1)

Comment: Thanks very much ! You are like an angel @Arnaldo  :)

Comment: @Jaideep Khare  so i can take $n$  as a comon factor

Comment: @FlameTrap Where did you see that? BTW it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @FlameTrap Oh!! Thanks. Fixed it.

Comment: @prayersmith Yes you can.

Comment: @Flame Trap  can you  elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: @prayersmith Are you saying to me to elaborate the answer?

Comment: @Jaideep Khare i need to know  if the index starting from $0$ makes any difference  in the solution

Comment: @prayersmith If I start from $r=1$ in the general term $T_n = 9r^2+6r+1$, I get first term as $T_1=16$, which is actually second term.Hence we need to start from $r=0$ so that $T_1=1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56958/discussion-between-prayer-smith-and-jaideep-khare).

Comment: The sum of $1$ should give $n+1$ instead of $n$ because we started with  $r=0$.  This spoils the divisibility by $n$ and the sum up to $n=3$ proves that.  There is no correct answer.